# Python - Comparing a string against the Unicode replacement-character

Tags: python, unicode, replace, utf-8, character

I have a really big work project (in Java) and the encoding was changed after a migration to UTF-8.
I'm coding a script in python to replace every "Unicode replacement character" (�) but i'm having trouble doing this line:

```
if ("�" in word) :
    // replace word for proper one
```

Obviously this doesn't work because the Python interpreter doesn't understand the special character. I looked it up and found something like u"\uFFD" but couldn't make it work.

**EDIT: I tried doing it in the Python IDLE shell and this message appears**
[image]

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Python 3 uses unicode for strings, and can detect if "�" is present in strings or not.

Comment: What's not working? Finding the character in a word? Or the replacement step?

Comment: You can see `"�"` in console if console doesn't know how to display some char - but it doesn't mean that you have `"�"` in text in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I'll delete this answer if I'm misunderstanding your question, but in Python 3 (and from further testing Python 2 as well) you can handle Unicode characters like "�" just like any other character:

```
def replace_special_characters(sentence):
    return sentence.replace("�", "REPLACEMENT")

sentence_a = "foo bar"
sentence_b = "baz �"

print(replace_special_characters(sentence_a))
print(replace_special_characters(sentence_b))
```

**Output**

```
foo bar
baz REPLACEMENT
```

Comment: works in Python 2 I think. well at least on my linux box 2.7.10, it works

Comment: @MooingRawr Yeah, just tested this on a Python 2.7.10 IDLE shell and it works fine, although the first time I ran it it came up with a warning about putting some "utf-8" declaration at the top.

Comment: @Tagc I tried doing it in the Python IDLE shell and this message appears img.ctrlv.in/img/17/01/16/587cfb8b91399.png